# How to pass parameters delete method? (django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have model **Like** and want to delete this object with parameters.
it's code ->

`Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()).delete()`

and also I have signal

**i want user parameter here**

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Like)
def delete_like(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    instance.question.point -= 1
    instance.question.save()
```

I want something like that

`Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()).delete(status="Testing")`

and after using this status while deleting

P.S **status = "Testing"** is for example

Comment: It is not clear at all to me what you aim to achieve and what is not working currently.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i want question.point subtract or do not subtract according to the parameter passed in the delete method

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem status = "Testing" Show you for example

Answer (score 0):

delete() doesn't accept any parameter [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#delete). Try filtering with your requirements and perform the delete method on that.